# Creating a fixed navbar

Tags: navigation

I have the following navbar which is meant to scroll down as the page scrolls and change position if the device is taller than it is wide, it is meant to display somewhere on the left if the device is taller than wide, and on top otherwise.

i have this code for the execution:

`#navbar li { display: inline; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; }`

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {`

`#navbar li { display: block; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; }`

And i need code to make the navigation area:

`<div id = "navbar">`
`<input type="button" value="previous page" action="" name="previous page" onclick="doPrev();"/>
<input type="button" value="next page" action="" name="next page" onclick="doNext();"/>
<li><a href="numofchapters.htm">Number of chapters</a></li>`

`</div>`

Visible at all times, even while scrolling. How is this done???

Comment: Please provide working fiddle.

Comment: What??? You should at least have an idea of how to do at least one of these things???

Comment: In working fiddle it would be easier for us to provide solution. It is not that we should write it from scratch. You will have to show What have you tried?

Comment: Ben this is not a "write code for me" shop -- you leave your question up after it is finished so that others can learn from what you asked.  I've reverted your edit which removed the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add "position: fixed;" to your CSS and also assign a z-index higher than your other containters (some people use "z-index: 100;"). I learned about z-index on this very site, try searching! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A first try would be to add

```
position: fixed;
```

to the CSS of the wrapping element of the menu.
In your case: `#navbar ul`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LtBh6/

Add

```
#navbar {
position: fixed;
}
```

to your CSS file.  You may now need to add margin to the elements below.